# Speaking negatively about someone - not about an Aveirah or Middah

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, sin, lashon-hara-slander, chofetz-chaim

When speaking negatively about someone, whether about an Aveirah that person did, or a bad middah he has, one transgresses the aveirah of Lashon Hara. The same is true if a negative remark can cause some type of loss to the person spoken about.This is described at length in the Sefer Chafetz Chaim.

I am looking for the source (in the Chofetz Chaim) that speaking other negative things, not related to an aveirah or middah and cannot cause harm, about someone is also not allowed because of Lashon Hara.

For example, is telling a humorous story about someone who slipped on a banana peel Lashon Hara? It is not an Aveirah, nor a middah.

Comment: Not directly from the Chofetz Chaim, but in Mesilas Yesharim, it writes: One's words should be of honoring [others] not of belittling them. Likewise scripture says: "he who belittles his fellow lacks sense" (Mishlei 11:12). So yes, telling about someones misfortune, e.g. someone slipped and fell, this is belittling someone, and can harm the person.

Comment: @Shmuel does the Mesilas Yesharim speak to the transgression of Lashon Hara when this is done? I am not questioning the immorality.